# SSRS - using Visual Studio 2008 vs Visual Studio 2010

Tags: reporting-services

I have been working with SSRS for 2 years now in a SQL 2008 R2 environment. I have been using Visual Studio 2008 BIDS interface to develop and maintain  reports. Frankly, I am appalled by the quality of this software and it's Preview option. I have been documenting my gripes (reached number 48). Simple things like unsupported copy/paste using keyboard shortcuts, appalling error reporting, very flaky subreport concept, awful intellisense, missing undo option in many circumstances etc etc. I have lost many hours of development time working around issues such as these. I am dumbfounded as to how software could ever be released in such a state.

Anyway, I currently have no option to move from the SQL 2008 R2 environment but I am wondering whether, if I start to use the Visual Studio 2010 environment as my IDE (rather than Visual Studio 2008) whether I might see any improvements?

Any help with this would be appreciated and thank you in advance.

Comment: Move up to at least 2012 it's a lot better

Comment: Out of interest, why not use Report Builder?

Comment: My life became so much easier when I switched to Report Builder 3.  Takes away all of the extraneous crap.

Comment: Or you could install VS2015 Community Edition plus SSDT and then you can develop in a modern environment that can target any edition of  SSRS; use Visual Studio Team Services for version control etc.

Comment: Thanks all. I will try and get hold of VS2015. Is Report Builder 3 free does anyone know?